# Wrong use of GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql

i'm having a real problem with a query. The database entity are:

```
Paziente (Codice_Fiscale, Nome_Paziente, Cognome_Paziente, Data_Nascita, Luogo_Nascita)
Appuntamento (Codice_Appuntamento, Data_Appuntamento, Ora_Appuntamento, Codice_Fiscale)
Intervento (Codice_Intervento, Tipo_Intervento, Sala_Intervento, Data_Intervento, Ora_Intervento, Codice_Fiscale_Paziente, ID_Dentista)
Dentista (ID_Dentista, Nome_Dentista, Cognome_Dentista)
```

I need to do a query that shows a list of appointment grouped by type of intervention.
It should be something like:

```
Tipo_Intervento       COUNT(*)  
Chirurgia dentale      1
Cura carie             2
Estrazione dentale     1
Pulizia dentale        3
```

I can do this correctly when i use this query:

```
SELECT intervento.Tipo_Intervento, COUNT(*)
FROM intervento
GROUP BY intervento.Tipo_Intervento
```

But i need to link the database "intervento" to "appuntamento" ('cause it's an exercise) and when i use this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT appuntamento.Codice_Appuntamento) AS Numero_Appuntamenti, intervento.Tipo_Intervento AS Tipologia_intervento
FROM appuntamento, intervento
WHERE appuntamento.Codice_Fiscale = intervento.Codice_Fiscale_Paziente
GROUP BY intervento.Tipo_Intervento
```

I obtain the wrong value:

```
Numero_Appuntamenti      Tipologia_intervento   
2                        Chirurgia dentale
4                        Cura carie
2                        Estrazione dentale
3                        Pulizia dentale
```

The problem is in the GROUP BY intervento.Tipo_Intervento, that increase the number of appointments, in fact if i use GROUP BY appuntamento.Codice_Appuntamento i obtain:

```
Numero_Appuntamenti  Tipologia_intervento   
1                    Pulizia dentale
1                    Estrazione dentale
1                    Pulizia dentale
1                    Cura carie
1                    Cura carie
1                    Pulizia dentale
1                    Estrazione dentale
```

That is right, but i need it to be grouped.

Does someone can help me? (forgive my bad english, as you can see it's not my language)

EDIT: This is the table "appuntamento":

```
Codice_Appuntamento Data_Appuntamento   Ora_Appuntamento    Codice_Fiscale  
        001           2020-05-05    16:00:00.000000     RSSMRA80A01H501U
        002           2020-07-03    16:30:00.000000     VRDGPP85E02F205P
        003          2020-06-05     16:00:00.000000     RSSMRA80A01H501U
        004          2020-08-14     17:15:00.000000     BNCGNN83D03L219B
        005           2020-08-27    17:45:00.000000     BNCGNN83D03L219B
        006          2020-07-05     16:00:00.000000     RSSMRA80A01H501U
        007          2020-09-13     17:20:00.000000     VRDGPP85E02F205P
```

And this the table "intervento"

```
Codice_Intervento Tipo_Intervento   Sala_Intervento    Data_Intervento   Ora_Intervento   Codice_Fiscale_Paziente   ID_Dentista     
    A_001          Pulizia dentale        1             2020-05-05       16:00:00.000000    RSSMRA80A01H501U            D_001
    A_002          Estrazione dentale     2             2020-07-03        16:30:00.000000   VRDGPP85E02F205P            D_003
    A_003          Pulizia dentale        1             2020-06-05        16:00:00.000000   RSSMRA80A01H501U            D_001
    A_004          Cura carie             3             2020-08-14        17:15:00.000000   BNCGNN83D03L219B            D_001
    A_005          Chirurgia dentale      5             2020-08-27        17:45:00.000000   BNCGNN83D03L219B            D_002
    A_006          Pulizia dentale        1             2020-07-05        16:00:00.000000   RSSMRA80A01H501U            D_001
    A_007          Cura carie             3             2020-09-13         17:20:00.000000  VRDGPP85E02F205P            D_002
```

"Codice fiscale" and "ID_Dentista" are the foreing key, thery are the primary key of "paziente" and "dentista"

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please use JOINs instead of putting all table into the FROM clause.

Comment: Hi, i don't know how to use it, i'm really a beginner, can you explain?

Comment: You might note that in your last result your 'Chirurgia dentale' is missing, since there is no [appuntamento] for it. A LEFT JOIN would keep all [intervento] that have no match on the other table.

Comment: Please provide sample data from both tables. It is unclear how to two tables relate to each other (especially for someone that does not speak Italian).

Comment: Sincerely i'm just a student and i never used the JOIN, but i always linked the table using a common attribute (like this case where ther's a common foreign key, the fiscal code of the patient. I tried your way but i still obtain this: 2  Chirurgia dentale, 4  Cura carie, 2  Estrazione dentale, 9  Pulizia dentale

Comment: No, wait, that can not be. 'Chirurgia dentale' has at least 2 [appuntamento] according to your previous resultset.

Comment: I think that's my fault, the result i want to obtain are 1, 2, 1, 3 /the first table), not 2, 4, 2, 3 (the second one). However i'm updating the post adding the table, so you can see my data

Comment: @GMB i add the two table data

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT(DISTINCT field)` returns how many unique [appuntamento].[Codice_Appuntamento] are found for each [intervento].[Tipo_Intervento]. If I read your question right, you just want to remove the `DISTINCT`.

That should work if you use a `LEFT JOIN`. Your way of putting together tables rule out any [appuntamento] without a [intervento]

```sql
SELECT COUNT(appuntamento.Codice_Appuntamento) AS Numero_Appuntamenti, intervento.Tipo_Intervento AS Tipologia_intervento
FROM appuntamento
LEFT JOIN intervento ON appuntamento.Codice_Fiscale = intervento.Codice_Fiscale_Paziente
GROUP BY intervento.Tipo_Intervento
```

Comment: @dasdasdasd please clarify what your desired result is in the question.

Comment: I just want to obtain the result of the first query i posted, but using GROUP BY and using both of the entity

Comment: to do what? why are you adding the 2nd table if you dont want any values from it?

Comment: I add the second one beacuse it's what i see when i do the query in the way i want, and those are the wrong value, while i want to obtain the value of the first one but doing a query that include GROUP BY and both "appuntamento" and "intervento"

Comment: I edited my answer. See if thats what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, but i stil obtain increased values

Comment: Yes, the ```COUNT()``` now returns how many [appuntamento] each [intervento] has.

Comment: I see, but the values are still incorrect, despite i have obtained all the missing field like chirurgia dentale

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT max(i.Tipo_Intervento), count(a. Codice_Appuntamento)
FROM intervento as i left join appuntamento as a on i.Codice_Fiscale_Paziente = a.Codice_Fiscale 
GROUP BY i.Sala_Intervento
```

Comment: I did a small change. I figured out the `Tipo_Intervento` was repeating, so now i used Sala_Intervento to group the records.

Answer (score 0):

This will work on mysql 5.6,  not on higher versions :

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sDXoDdMWsPVkTheoaWkx1i/0

```
SELECT  i.Tipo_Intervento,tmp.Numero_Appuntamenti,a.*
FROM intervento i
LEFT JOIN  appuntamento a ON a.Codice_Fiscale = i.Codice_Fiscale_Paziente
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Numero_Appuntamenti,Tipo_Intervento 
           from intervento
           GROUP BY Tipo_Intervento)  AS tmp ON i.Tipo_Intervento=tmp.Tipo_Intervento
GROUP BY i.Tipo_Intervento
```

Comment: Can you explai nme how it works? And if is possible, there's a way to do this query without the use of two left join and the use of this tmp? (that i don't even know what it is?). Because this is an exercise and we don't even studied those things, so i can't use them in my exercise